# Remove rows with only NAN from large a dataset

Tags: perl

I have a large data set (12,000 rows X 14 columns); the first 4 rows as below:

```
x1  y1  0.02    NAN NAN NAN NAN NAN NAN 0.004   NAN NAN NAN NAN
x2  y2  NAN 0.003   NAN 10  NAN 0.03    NAN 0.004   NAN NAN NAN NAN
x3  y3  NAN NAN NAN NAN NAN NAN NAN NAN NAN NAN NAN NAN
x4  y4  NAN 0.004   NAN NAN NAN NAN 10  NAN NAN 30  NAN 0.004
```

I need to remove any row with "NAN" in columns 3-14 and then output the rest of the dataset. I wrote the following code:

```
#!usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;
use diagnostics;

open(IN, "<", "file1.txt") or die "Can't open file for reading:$!";

open(OUT, ">", "file2.txt") or die "Can't open file for writing:$!";

my $header = <IN>;
print OUT $header;

my $at_line = 0;

my $col3;
my $col4;
my $col5;
my $col6;
my $col7;
my $col8;
my $col9;
my $col10;
my $col11;
my $col13;
my $col14;
my $col15;

while (<IN>){
chomp;
my @sections = split(/\t/);

$col3 = $sections[2];
$col4 = $sections[3];;
$col5 = $sections[4];
$col6 = $sections[5];
$col7 = $sections[6];
$col8 = $sections[7];
$col9 = $sections[8];
$col10 = $sections[9];
$col11 = $sections[10];
$col13 = $sections[11];
$col14 = $sections[12];
$col15 = $sections[13];

if ($col3 eq "NAN" && $col4 eq "NAN" && $col5 eq "NAN" && $col6 eq "NAN" && $col7 eq "NAN" && $col8 eq "NAN" && $col9 eq "NAN" && $col10 eq "NAN" 
&& $col11 eq "NAN" && $col12 eq "NAN" && $col13 eq "NAN" && $col14 eq "NAN" && $col5 eq "NAN"){
    $at_line = $.;
    }   
    else {
        print OUT "$_\n";
    }
}

close(IN);
close(OUT);
```

Running this code gave the following error:

```
Use of uninitialized value $col3 in string eq at filter.pl
    line 46, <IN> line 2 (#1)
```

How can I make this program work? Thanks.

Comment: When you see `my $col3; my $col4; ...` you should be thinking "array", not "more scalars".

Comment: This is not an error, it's just a warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while (<IN>) {
    my @values = (split( /\s+/)[2..13];
    my $nan_count = grep { $_ eq 'NAN' } @values;
    print $_ unless $nan_count == 12;
}
```

Joseph R. has the right approach for splitting the lines.

`grep` returns the number of matches when called in scalar context, so this gives an alternate way of checking to see if all columns equal NAN.

Comment: RickF: I removed [2..13] and then it worked brilliantly. Many thanks to you and everyone else for their valuable contributions.

Answer (score 4):

One-liner:

```
$ perl -lane 'print if join("", @F[2..13]) ne "NAN" x 12' <file1.txt >file2.txt
```

Comment: `grep { $_ ne "NAN" }` is another option.

Answer (score 4):

Zaid's one-liner is the best solution for your particular case. In general, instead of defining this many scalars, your pattern should rather be

```
my @required_columns = (split /\s+/)[2..13]
```

It seems the error you're getting is due to the fact that you're splitting on tabs while your dataset is space-delimited. Remember, `split` takes a regex not a string.

Comment: Thanks all. I have tried all the 3 suggestions and for some reason, I ended up with the same content of my input file in the output file.